# Admob Reward Ads for Webview

Tags: webview, admob

I am developing an application and would like to add award-winning advertising to the application. If the ad is followed, it will redirect to WebView. **If the ad is not tracked, let's not redirect it**. I'm new at this. I'd appreciate it if you could explain it in a clear way.
Note: I'm sorry for the bad english.